# Mobile service provider in Germany: Intensive Data Usage

Tags: europe, germany, mobile-operators

I will be traveling to Germany for a long term. I wish to get a mobile provider which has good network coverage (I prefer staying on a country side) for mobile internet (say 3GB) along with free data usage across EU.

Any pointers?

PS: I don't make many voice calls so data is of prime concern for me.

Comment: How long do you plan to stay?

Comment: More than two years @Austin

Comment: Right now, O2 has a plan that includes using a part of your monthly data volume when roaming. I have 3GB at home and 1GB in EU roaming for example. That also includes free calls to the current country, to Germany and no roaming costs for you when you get called while in roaming. But the roaming costs will go away soon anyway. Note that typically mobile contracts in Germany have a 24 month period and need to be cancelled well in advance. Some providers offer month-by-month cancellation but then it costs about 5 Euros more per month. I don't know any prepaid with free data roaming.

Answer (score 1):

I live in a rural part of Germany. I get very good coverage with Deutsche Telekom. There are other companies but my friends have trouble in the rural spots. I also have a prepay plan.

Here is the link and you can look at plans and International plans.
https://www.telekom.de/start

Comment: Do you mean Deutsche Telecom?

Comment: Yes it is Deutsche Telecom.

Comment: You may also consider congstar, a subsidiary of Deutsche Telekom using the same network, but usually for cheaper rates.